# dask computation not executing in parallel

Tags: python, concurrency, python-multiprocessing, dask, castra

I have a directory of json files that I am trying to convert to a dask DataFrame and save it to castra.
There are 200 files containing O(10**7) json records between them.
The code is very simple largely following tutorial examples.

```
import dask.dataframe as dd
import dask.bag as db
import json
txt = db.from_filenames('part-*.json')
js = txt.map(json.loads)
df = js.to_dataframe()
cs=df.to_castra("data.castra")
```

I am running it on a 32 core machine, but the code only utilizes one core at 100%.
My understanding from the docs is that this code execute in parallel.
Why is it not?
Did I misunderstand something?

Answer (score 8):

Your final collection is a dask dataframe, which uses threads by default, you will have to explicitly tell dask to use processes.

You can do this globally

```
import dask
dask.config.set(scheduler='multiprocessing')
```

Or do this just on the `to_castra` call

```
df.to_castra("data.castra", scheduler='multiprocessing')
```

Also, just as a warning, Castra was mostly an experiment.  It's decently fast but also not nearly mature as something like HDF5 or Parquet.

Comment: Thanks, but it did not work for me, `df.to_castra` does not take a `get` and the `dask.set_options` approach does not seem to have any effect. I understand that Castra is experimental, but it seems to fit many use cases for me very nicely. I often have medium size data that I want to be able use as a DataFrame with quick save and load times. Spark or HDFS is ovekill and Pandas doesn't quiet stretch that far.

Comment: Ah, yes indeed you're correct.  It looks like we've purposefully hardcoded the single-core scheduler into to_castra.  I think this was because we ran into poor memory performance because intermediate results would pile up as things made data ready but the disk couldn't keep up.  Still, this should be optional.  I've hotfixed a quick fix in master at https://github.com/dask/dask/commit/cb4cc8127028fc736e295c114acfbeed15b71617

Comment: Thanks! I have tried it. It does get the code running in parallel but it crashes at the end. There are a few other issues. I put the specifics in the notes on the CL.

Comment: The syntax for newer versions of dask is now:
`import dask.multiprocessing
dask.config.set(scheduler=dask.multiprocessing.get)`

Comment: What if it still uses only 1 cpu?